# How to multiply two values without clicking a button - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YFgkB/6/

```
 <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="5">
 <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="">
 <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="calc()">Calculate</a>
 <input type="text" name="output" id="output" value="">
```

Javascript

```
 function calc(){
   var textValue1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
   var textValue2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;

   document.getElementById('output').value = textValue1 * textValue2; 
 }
```

Here everything working fine when click on calculate link, it multiplies both the text input numbers and shows the result in the third box but I need it to automatic multiplication with the link calculate.

I mean user can enter a value in the 2nd text box so it automatically multplies and shows the result in the 3rd textbox without any button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/YFgkB/10/)

Try this

```
$("#input2,#input1").keyup(function () {
    $('#output').val($('#input1').val() * $('#input2').val());
});
```

Comment: thanks suppose the value in the text box comes from the database according to dropdown, so then the answer in the third box should automatically update. How to do that?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectprice').on('change', function() {

     //Do the AJAX request for price here, like:
     $.get("get_price.php?prodId="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
          //Set the retrieved price:
         $('input[name=price]').val(data);

   document.getElementById('output_frame').innerHTML = data;
  });
 });
});

Comment: yeah what you do is correct. there you have to add this $('#output').val($('#input1').val() * $('#input2').val());

Comment: @razor try this http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/YFgkB/12/   and please mark the answer as correct if you found it helpful

Answer (score 7):

Use `onkeyup="calc()"` on `input` elements

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" onkeyup="calc()"value="5">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" onkeyup="calc()" value="">
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/YFgkB/7/)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

you can call `calc()` function on `blur` event

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/YFgkB/9/)**

```
function calc(){
   var textValue1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
   var textValue2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;

   if($.trim(textValue1) != '' && $.trim(textValue2) != ''){
      document.getElementById('output').value = textValue1 * textValue2; 
    }
}

$(function(){
   $('#input1, #input2').blur(calc);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

using jquery..

try this

```
 $('#input1,#input2').keyup(function(){
     var textValue1 =$('#input1').val();
     var textValue2 = $('#input2').val();

    $('#output').val(textValue1 * textValue2); 
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/riqizi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Try this!

```js
function add() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
  document.getElementById("c").value = x * y;
}
```

```html
Enter 1st Number :
<input type="text" id="a">
<br>
<br>Enter 2nd Number :
<input type="text" id="b" onkeyup="add()">
<br>
<br>Result :
<input type="text" id="c">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" onchange="calc()">
```

You may want to add a check for a blank value, etc.