# Difference between two input value without button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form i have 2 select menu and one input menu

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Civil Works</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <select id="cpercentage" name="txt_cpercentage" class="form-control" onkeyup="calc()">

      <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0%</option>
        <option value="5">5%</option>
        <option value="10">10%</option>
        <option value="15">15%</option>
        <option value="20">20%</option>
        <option value="25">25%</option>
        <option value="30">30%</option>
        <option value="35">35%</option>
        <option value="40">40%</option>
        <option value="45">45%</option>
        <option value="50">50%</option>
        <option value="55">55%</option>
        <option value="60">60%</option>
        <option value="65">65%</option>
        <option value="70">70%</option>
        <option value="75">75%</option>
        <option value="80">80%</option>
        <option value="85">85%</option>
        <option value="90">90%</option>
        <option value="95">95%</option>
        <option value="100">100%</option>
    </select>
  </div>
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Electrical Works</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <select id="epercentage" name="txt_epercentage" class="form-control"  >

      <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0%</option>
        <option value="5">5%</option>
        <option value="10">10%</option>
        <option value="15">15%</option>
        <option value="20">20%</option>
        <option value="25">25%</option>
        <option value="30">30%</option>
        <option value="35">35%</option>
        <option value="40">40%</option>
        <option value="45">45%</option>
        <option value="50">50%</option>
        <option value="55">55%</option>
        <option value="60">60%</option>
        <option value="65">65%</option>
        <option value="70">70%</option>
        <option value="75">75%</option>
        <option value="80">80%</option>
        <option value="85">85%</option>
        <option value="90">90%</option>
        <option value="95">95%</option>
        <option value="100">100%</option>
    </select>
  </div>
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Mechanical Works</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" id="mpercentage" name="txt_mpercentage" class="form-control" readonly > 

  </div>
    </form>
```

I use this code in javascript to calculate the difference and this difference will be 100-(select1+select2) without click any button

```
<script>

function calc() {
    var textValue1 = document.getElementById('cpercentage').value;
    var textValue2 = document.getElementById('epercentage').value;

    document.getElementById('mpercentage').value = 100-(textValue1 + textValue2);
}
</script>
```

but i don't have any result in the input field i don't know why can any body help to solve this problem 
after a search i see this in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699642/how-to-multiply-two-values-without-clicking-a-button-javascript)
but also didn't help

Answer (score 3):

Bind the `change` event to select elements,

```
document.getElementById('cpercentage').addEventListener('change', calc);
document.getElementById('epercentage').addEventListener('change', calc);
```

However, As you have tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), You can use

```
$('#cpercentage, #epercentage').on('change', calc )
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var cpercentage = document.getElementById('cpercentage');
  var epercentage = document.getElementById('epercentage');

  //Bind event handler
  cpercentage.addEventListener('change', calc);
  epercentage.addEventListener('change', calc);

  function calc() {
    var textValue1 = Number(cpercentage.value) || 0;
    var textValue2 = Number(epercentage.value) || 0;

    document.getElementById('mpercentage').value = 100 - (textValue1 + textValue2);
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Civil Works</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <select id="cpercentage" name="txt_cpercentage" class="form-control">

      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="0">0%</option>
      <option value="5">5%</option>
      <option value="10">10%</option>
      <option value="15">15%</option>
      <option value="20">20%</option>
      <option value="25">25%</option>
      <option value="30">30%</option>
      <option value="35">35%</option>
      <option value="40">40%</option>
      <option value="45">45%</option>
      <option value="50">50%</option>
      <option value="55">55%</option>
      <option value="60">60%</option>
      <option value="65">65%</option>
      <option value="70">70%</option>
      <option value="75">75%</option>
      <option value="80">80%</option>
      <option value="85">85%</option>
      <option value="90">90%</option>
      <option value="95">95%</option>
      <option value="100">100%</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Electrical Works</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <select id="epercentage" name="txt_epercentage" class="form-control">

      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="0">0%</option>
      <option value="5">5%</option>
      <option value="10">10%</option>
      <option value="15">15%</option>
      <option value="20">20%</option>
      <option value="25">25%</option>
      <option value="30">30%</option>
      <option value="35">35%</option>
      <option value="40">40%</option>
      <option value="45">45%</option>
      <option value="50">50%</option>
      <option value="55">55%</option>
      <option value="60">60%</option>
      <option value="65">65%</option>
      <option value="70">70%</option>
      <option value="75">75%</option>
      <option value="80">80%</option>
      <option value="85">85%</option>
      <option value="90">90%</option>
      <option value="95">95%</option>
      <option value="100">100%</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Mechanical Works</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" id="mpercentage" name="txt_mpercentage" class="form-control" readonly>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Satpal it didn't work for me no value appear in the third input

Comment: @m7md, I have updated snippet, wrap code in `window.onload`

Comment: @Satpal it didn't calcualte the second he do 100 - input1 only i don't know why

Comment: @m7md this should work if your html exactly what you have posted here.

Comment: @NedimHozić He tagged it JQuery, so JQuery solutions are fine. What makes you think he needs pure JS? Also, a JS solution is provided as well.

Comment: @Parvez it a part of html form but the select and the input i put it is the same

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are getting String by using this `document.getElementById('cpercentage').value`
so you have to parse it into integer to perform mathematical operations.

```
 <select id="epercentage" name="txt_epercentage" class="form-control" onchange="calc()" >
```

I have tried to call your function by select onchange and it is working fine
hope this will be help.

```
    <html>
<head></head><body>
<form method="post" action="">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Civil Works</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <select id="cpercentage" name="txt_cpercentage" class="form-control">

      <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0%</option>
        <option value="5">5%</option>
        <option value="10">10%</option>
        <option value="15">15%</option>
        <option value="20">20%</option>
        <option value="25">25%</option>
        <option value="30">30%</option>
        <option value="35">35%</option>
        <option value="40">40%</option>
        <option value="45">45%</option>
        <option value="50">50%</option>
        <option value="55">55%</option>
        <option value="60">60%</option>
        <option value="65">65%</option>
        <option value="70">70%</option>
        <option value="75">75%</option>
        <option value="80">80%</option>
        <option value="85">85%</option>
        <option value="90">90%</option>
        <option value="95">95%</option>
        <option value="100">100%</option>
    </select>
  </div>
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Electrical Works</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <select id="epercentage" name="txt_epercentage" class="form-control" onchange="calc()" >

      <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">0%</option>
        <option value="5">5%</option>
        <option value="10">10%</option>
        <option value="15">15%</option>
        <option value="20">20%</option>
        <option value="25">25%</option>
        <option value="30">30%</option>
        <option value="35">35%</option>
        <option value="40">40%</option>
        <option value="45">45%</option>
        <option value="50">50%</option>
        <option value="55">55%</option>
        <option value="60">60%</option>
        <option value="65">65%</option>
        <option value="70">70%</option>
        <option value="75">75%</option>
        <option value="80">80%</option>
        <option value="85">85%</option>
        <option value="90">90%</option>
        <option value="95">95%</option>
        <option value="100">100%</option>
    </select>
  </div>
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Mechanical Works</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" id="mpercentage" name="txt_mpercentage" class="form-control" readonly > 

  </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script>

function calc() {
    var textValue1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('cpercentage').value);
    var textValue2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('epercentage').value);
    var x = 100-(textValue1+textValue2);
    alert(x);
    document.getElementById('mpercentage').value=x;

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: it give me NAN what i do ?

Comment: let me edit my answer 
it is working fine in my machine.

Comment: i put the code in a different page and i have a result i don't know why in the form already i have did it didn't work this is make me crazy